# Fingerprinting routers using timestamps

Tags: router, icmp

We all know that physical machines can be fingerprinted using timestamps of a clock in the NIC. My question that is it possible to fingerprint/uniquely identify routers based on timestamps?
If yes then do routers send separate timestamps in ip packets along with timestamps of NIC?

Comment: Authentication is a term often used for fingerprinting. that might help you in searching for what you are looking for.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing NIC timestamps (only available to the OS), and TCP timestamp fingerprinting, which allows a remote host to identify the OS (and possibly the individual device).

Routers don't modify TCP segments -- what you see is the segment from the originating host.  That's why you can fingerprint remote hosts.

In order to identify a router, you need the router to generate TCP traffic, for example, from a administrative session with the router itself.